# I am getting an error when setting up mysql

Tags: mysql, installation

I am a new programer for sql.
I have install the SQL application on my laptop then I am going over to my computer and clicking on properties then changing the advance system settings from there and from there I am going to the environment variable and I am adding a new path for sql

I am going to cmd prompt in my Windows to install the database but it's giving me and error, which says cannot find the file specified

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujAoX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your PATH it's hard to know what's up. But generally speaking, make sure the mysql path can be found, and if it can be found, make sure that the employees.sql is indeed in the correct folder.